# For simple spring web application spring mvc with jsp+tiles is the best choice?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

For simple spring web application spring mvc with jsp+apache tiles is the best choice? or should prefer thymeleaf or jsp+any tiles?

Comment: use thymeleaf good example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-thymeleaf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple spring web application spring mvc with jsp+apache tiles is the best choice?

**answer is YES it was a good choice before but now use thymeleaf.**

should prefer thymeleaf or jsp+any tiles?

**answer : use thymeleaf fragment layouts which will serve your purpose as jsp tiles do.**

Comment: If you are not already familiar with Thymleaf I don't think it worth the effort to get used to work with ... if we are talking about a individual simple spring web application.

Comment: exactly..that is why the answer is YES.

Comment: Alien and Flocke thanks for answer..i am not familiar with thymeleaf.

Comment: then go for jsp +tiles.

Comment: thank u alien..i need one more suggestion? what is the best alternative ui component for primeface?

Comment: sorry man..no idea about that...and please upvote or accept if it helped you.